# Include chapter's page or word count into heading

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there any way to include the (automatically generated) word or page count of a chapter into its chapter heading? It would come handy to have a good overview of the length of chapter when working with the navigation pane.

Answer (score 0):

usually each chapter goes in an individual section, if so, you can insert a field called [SectionPages] in your heading. this field will always shows the number or pages in the current section.

go to INSERT Tab in the Ribbon then press "Quick Parts" icon, then select "Field" scroll down until you find "SectionPages" and then press ok.[sectionPages Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAczT.png)